# How do I connect these faces up without adding too many quads using retopology?

Tags: faces, topology

I am trying to retopo a sculpture and I have little experience. How do I connect an area with small quads and high density up with an area with large quads without messing up the flow? Should I be doing the spikes in my image separately?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Hi, this is the "usual" workflow how to proceed from a low-poly to high-poly (or vice-versa) and keeping quads - You could repeat the process multiple times so there is no problem to start with 2 quads and finish with 8 or more. Try it if it will work for You cause I dunno how "dense" your original mesh is so maybe this could not fit properly (too many steps needed).

Hope it helps, Buddy.

Sincerely, Jan